# Left remainder when dividing by $x-b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Give a polynomial $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + ... a_n x^n \in \mathcal R[x]$ ($\mathcal R $ is any ring with unity), the book says when dividing $p(x)$ by $x-b \quad (b\in \mathcal R)$, the left remainder is 
$$r_L := a_0+ ba_1+...+b^n a_n.$$

When dividing by $x-b$, the left remainder is $r_L$ for which $$ p(x) = (x-b)q(x) + r_L;$$ and the right remainder is $r_R$ for which$$p(x) = h(x) (x-b) + r_R.$$

I know how to show the right remainder is $r_R = a_0+ a_1b+...+ a_nb^n$
$$p(x) - r_R = (a_1x - a_1b) + ... + (a_n x^n -  a_nb^n)$$
$$p(x) - r_R = a_1 (x - b)+ ... +  a_n(x^n - b^n)  \\
= \big[a_1+ ... +  a_n(x^{n-1} + bx^{n-2} ... + b^{n-1})\big](x-b).$$

But for left remainder
$$p(x) - r_L = (a_1x - ba_1) + ... + (a_n x^n - b^n a_n)$$
is there a way to factor out $a_1$ in each term so that 
$$p(x) - r_L = (x - b)a_1 + ... + (x^n - b^n) a_n?$$

Thank you very much!

**Edit: Thanks to [egreg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/62967/egreg), the elements in $\mathcal{R}$ commutes with $x$.**

Comment: How do you define left remainder?

Comment: @EugenCovaci left remainder is $$ p(x) = (x-b)q(x) + r_L;$$ right remainder is $$p(x) = h(x) (x-b) + r_R.$$

Comment: How about $\mathcal R$?

Comment: @EugenCovaci Any ring with unity. is this result even correct?

Comment: Your $x$ commutes with every element of $R$, or it wouldn't be necessarily true that $xax=ax^2$. Polynomials in a noncommuting indeterminate are much more complicated than expressions like $a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know $x$ and the coefficients commute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: Thanks to [egreg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/62967/egreg), the elements in $\mathcal{R}$ commutes with $x$.